# Plotting multiple line graph using pandas and matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, pandas

I have the following data in a pandas dataframe

```
       date  template     score
0  20140605         0  0.138786
1  20140605         1  0.846441
2  20140605         2  0.766636
3  20140605         3  0.259632
4  20140605         4  0.497366
5  20140606         0  0.138139
6  20140606         1  0.845320
7  20140606         2  0.762876
8  20140606         3  0.261035
9  20140606         4  0.498010
```

For every day there will be 5 templates and each template will have a score.

I want to plot the date in the x axis and score in the y axis and a separate line graph for each template in the same figure.

Is it possible to do this using matplotlib?

Comment: just fast-fast : try to start from the samples : http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/date_demo_rrule.html

Comment: @Louis Just to be clear. I want to know how to plot a grouped dataframe, not about processing dates

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use an approach like the following one. You can simply slice the dataframe according to the values of each template, and subsequently use the dates and scores for the plot.

```
from pandas import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import datetime as dt

#The following part is just for generating something similar to your dataframe
date1 = "20140605"
date2 = "20140606"

d = {'date': Series([date1]*5 + [date2]*5), 'template': Series(range(5)*2),
'score': Series([random() for i in range(10)]) } 

data = DataFrame(d)
#end of dataset generation

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

for temp in range(5):
    dat = data[data['template']==temp]
    dates =  dat['date']
    dates_f = [dt.datetime.strptime(date,'%Y%m%d') for date in dates]
    ax.plot(dates_f, dat['score'], label = "Template: {0}".format(temp))

plt.xlabel("Date")
plt.ylabel("Score")
ax.legend()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 56):

You can use the groupby method:

```
data.groupby("template").plot(x="date", y="score")
```

Comment: wow!! this is very crisp and gets the work done. It never occurred to me that I can group by template as well. If I had not accepted the previous answer, I would have accepted this one though.

Comment: is there a way to have the groups populate the legend?

Comment: To get them on a single figure I had to do `fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1); data.groupby("template").plot(x="date", y="score", ax=ax)`. It seems like there should be a nicer way to do this and get the legends right automatically as well.

Comment: I populated the legend using `plt.legend([v[0] for v in pr.groupby('template')['template']])`, which is messy but it works (groupby returns an iterator of data frames, within each data frame all values of `'template'` are the same so we just take the first).

Comment: This is great, it is the start of "small multiples" type charting with each groupby thing (in this case "template") getting its own chart. Just need to resize them so they are smaller. Nice.

Comment: @dshepherd isn't `plt.legend([v[0] for v in pr.groupby('template')])` enough? you just need the first item in the tuple returned by the groupby iterator.

Comment: I'm trying this approach but when I do the ".groupby("a").plot(x='date', y='score') , of course with a dataframe of my own, I receive 'Key Error' message. I grouped by two levels. Any clues why?

Answer (score 18):

I think the easiest way to plot this data with all the lines on the same graph is to pivot it such that each "template" value is a column:

```
pivoted = pandas.pivot_table(data, values='score', columns='template', index='date')
# Now there will be an index column for date and value columns for 0,1,2,3,4
pivoted.plot()
```

Comment: This is great also. Searched all over and this is best explanation of how pivot can be used with plot. I had two things I wanted to include on x axis. In my case I wanted month and day which were separate columns in my dataframe. So I used "index=['month','day']" which put both on x axis. Thanks!

Comment: I prefer this one over the accepted solution because: 1. no need to define ax separately, 2. unified way to play with different axes and groupings

Answer (score 1):

You can add the legend according to the groups with:

```
plt.legend(pr['template'], loc='best')
```

Comment: Actually you can't do this in general. `pr['template'] = [0,1,2,3,4,0,1,2,3,4]` in the case in the question, so it appears to work. However in general the first 4 elements of `pr['template']` will not contain each of the labels in the correct order. For example if you sort the data before plotting then `pr['template'][:4] = [0,0,1,1]`.